# nginx wildcard redirection configuration

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a web application that is running on `myhost.com`

When a user clicks on any of the buttons on the page I want to redirect them to the same page hosted on a different server.  So for example I want `myhost.com/x/happy` to redirect to `uathost.com/x/happy`

I am trying to use wild card so that every `/x/*` page is redirected appropriately.

I tried to use the below configuration but I still get a 404 from `myhost.com` when clicking on any of the buttons since `myhost.com` is not configured with those pages, thus my need for a redirect.

```
location ^~/r/ {
        proxy_pass https://uathost.com/$1;
    }
```

Comment: What is the `/r/` in your question? Do you mean `/x/`? You may need a space between `~` and `/` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)). Also, try: `proxy_pass https://uathost.com;`

Comment: sorry I meant /x/, typo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better asked on Webmasters or possibly on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

Well are you `redirecting` or `proxying`? The code you are showing is for a `proxy` to `uathost.com` not redirect.

For a redirect all should have to do is:

```
location /x {
   return 301 https://uathost.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I am trying to redirect not proxy.  I tried using the redirect as above but I am still getting a 404, but I can confirm https://uathost.com/x/happy exists

my code is as follows
    
    `location ^~ /x/ {
       return 301 https://uathost.com$request_uri;
    }`

Comment: The regex of yours is most likely not matching. Just try without regex and see if that gets you somewhere like my answer suggests.

Comment: without regex i still get the same errors, none of the subpages are redirecting whether it is `https://myhost.com/x/happy` or `https://myhost.com/x/sad`, none are redirecting to `uathost.com`

Comment: Are you reloading your config after the changes? As I know this works as I have it working.

Comment: yes I restarted nginx service. is that enough or am i missing a step? This redirect i have defined within /etc/nginx/nginx.conf within the server block of the configuration

Comment: have you tried `nginx -t` to see if there is an error in your config?

Comment: the issue was network services had blocked the port, it is now working.  I use the following to redirect all my subpages `location ^~ / { return 301 https://uathost.com$request_uri; }`

is there a way to route or proxypass my homepage only (myhost.com) to myhost.com:7231

Comment: Please open a new question so that it is seen by more people